# Where can I see the comments I flagged in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, comments

Where can I see the comments I flagged in YouTube? https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7687979?hl=en only contains  the reporting history for  flags on videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube doesn't have a page for that as of now.